# Mixing content types in multipart request

Tags: http, post, kotlin, dsl, multipart

I'm implementing a multipart request DSL for [kohttp](https://github.com/rybalkinsd/kohttp)
The most common use-case for it is file uploading.

However, I'm interested in what are the other common cases?

Regarding [w3 multipart docs](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html) it's reasonable to have `multipart/alternative` with alternative content representations and I'm going to support it.

Another case I figured out is sending `metadata` together with files:

```
POST
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=df5641e1-75d9-4d6d-ab26-66fdc7d1f682

--df5641e1-75d9-4d6d-ab26-66fdc7d1f682
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="filename"
Content-Length: 1046038

<file content here>
--df5641e1-75d9-4d6d-ab26-66fdc7d1f682
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 3

1=2
--df5641e1-75d9-4d6d-ab26-66fdc7d1f682--
```

What else I'm missing? It would be great hearing about others.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest checking latest HTTP Client from Java 11-12 to get first impression about possible reactive approach and features to support. Another source of inspiration is older Apache HTTP Client and of course OkHttp.

Refs:

- [Java 12 package docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/package-summary.html) and [this article](https://golb.hplar.ch/2019/01/java-11-http-client.html#upload-with-multipart)
- [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/streaming.html) and [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-multipart-upload)